# how to integrate watson conversation with Speech-to-text and text-to-speech APIs

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud, text-to-speech, speech-to-text, watson-conversation

This is my first experience of using IBM watson and I am stuck with integrating watson `conversation` with `speech-to-text` and `text-to-speech` api services using `node.js` platform.

Done with conversation part but can't find a method to make

input speech ==> output of STT => input of conversation => output of conversation => input to TTS ==> output speech

I have tried multiple ways but still can't get even 1% of success. Followed multiple github repos even this one too with most forks https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/node-sdk and multiple`tjbot recipes`, etc still no results.

Can anyone here guide me with the right method?

[the error with this link is attached below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uopi2.png)

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE] so we can help you better, along with research and details. What multiple ways have you tried? Why have they failed?

Comment: watson has actually a fully working [demo](https://speech-to-text-demo.ng.bluemix.net/) heres the github repo: https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/speech-to-text-nodejs

Comment: You seem to have problems with Node.js, not with the Watson services. Where is the code and the flow of commands?

Comment: i have already tried this demo already @kugtas and its working fine but its running separately not with my specified localhost.

Comment: i have used code provided in this link [https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/node-sdk] as it is and just followed the instructions and accordingly updated my credentials for the services. the error with this application is attached in the link in my question.

Answer (score 0):

does this help? I think this demo is similar to what you are doing. It is using STT, TTS, Conversation I believe.

https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/speech-javascript-sdk/tree/master/examples

https://speech-dialog.mybluemix.net/
https://github.com/nfriedly/speech-dialog

Answer (score 0):

There are some great examples that you can download, and play around with on the [Watson Starter Kits Page](https://console.bluemix.net/developer/watson/starter-kits).

Create a few of them and download the code, and then plunder what you need for your app or use one of the starter kits as the beginning of your app.

Starter kits on the page linked above that I think can help:

- Watson Speech to Text Basic
- [Watson Assistant Basic](https://console.bluemix.net/developer/watson/starter-kits/watson-assistant-basic)
- Watson Text to Speech Basic

Each of the starter kits listed above are available in Node and have README.md files to help you set everything up.